# Link errors with AutoSeededRandomPool when using Xcode and libc++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, crypto++

Trying to develop simple c++ stuff in xcode for the first time. I haven't done c++ for a while, nor do I usually use a mac so bear with me if this is trivial.

I have simply grabbed the AutoSeededRandomPool example source from here: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator#AutoSeededRandomPool

I used macports to grab libcryptopp +universal (the non universal one didnt work either though), and I have added libcryptopp.a to the 'link binaries with  libraries' build phase for my target.

During the build I get 22 errors, which you can see for yourself here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoryB.jpg

Using xcode 4.6.2 on oldish Lion OS X macbook pro.

Have I missed something obvious here? Thanks for your help

Comment: Please post an excerpt of your link errors; and not an image of them on another site. When a picture is on another site, Stack Overflow visitors cannot search for similar problems on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the source of the problem was linking with the libc++ standard library rather than the more standard libstdc++ library. Xcode and Mac OS X targets were not a problem.

If I link against libstdc++ then the linking errors disappear. For future reference the giveaway seems to be the std::**__1** namespacing visible in the errors, although with hindsight perhaps it should have been obvious that a library ported from linux would most likely be using the libstdc++ library.

Comment: That's actually discussed on another Crypto++ wiki page, but it would not be easy for you to find. The page its located on is [iOS (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_%28Command_Line%29#Xcode_Project). Crypto++ does *not* have a page dedicated to OS X/Xcode, but that's probably where it should be for you to find.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the correct compiler — The project you mention states the requirement is:

- Xcode 3.2.5,
- Xcode 4.0 and GCC 4.2,
- targeting Apple iOS

...It appears you're using `clang++`

http://www.cryptopp.com/#platforms

Also this says iOS, not OS X - That could certainly cause some issues as well. Why bother messing with this crypto library anyway? Use Apple's or one that was meant specifically to be used with OS X. It's of course your choice, but it certainly doesn't make it any easier going  this route.

Comment: I *think* the Crypto++ web page is a bit dated. OS X and Clang is fine. I keep Wikipedia's web page up to date because I can edit it. See [Crypto++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto%2B%2B). As for why use it, that's easy: (1) richer set of primitives and algorithms, (2) all the benefits of C++ (like OOP,  buffer management, automatic cleanup), and (3) its cross platform (BSDs, Linux, iOS, OS X, Windows, Solaris, etc). Using `CommonCrypto` or `CryptoTransform` only works for one platform.